# How to change font of a particular row of gridview

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, fonts

I have created an application which allows the user to select his/her desired font to enter his/her details. These details are stored in sql server database with the selected font name. Now when CMD of the company looks the report, the grid view should show all the data with each row's changed font name. Like if user selects Russian Language then the row data should show in Russian language in the grid view and the other row in other language which was being selected by the user.
Is it really possible or i have to use some another control. Please help.
Thanks in Advance.. My code is :-

```
Private Sub GV1_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GV1.RowDataBound
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        If e.Row.Cells(6).Text.ToString() = "M" Then
            e.Row.Font.Name = "Kruti Dev 040"
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

But still the font of the row is not changing...

Comment: have you tried to explicitly change the text font of each cell. i.e e.row.cells(6).Text.Font.Name = ""

Comment: No, I didn't tried this yet. Let me go through it and get back to you.

Comment: cool no problem. Ill write the answer and could you give me the thumbs up on it. Much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Private Sub GV1_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles
GV1.RowDataBound
If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
    If e.Row.Cells(6).Text.ToString() = "M" Then
        e.row.cells(6).Text.Font.Name = "Kruti Dev 040"
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the UI designer for the gridView. Under 'Appearance' choose 'Format Conditions'. [image]